# Density of smooth compact support function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

I'm looking for a proof of this fact - which a professor stated during lesson - concerning smooth compact support functions:

"Let $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} $ and $C^\infty_{c}((a,b))$ the set of $C^\infty$ functions $(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with compact support and
$C_0[a,b])$ the set of continuous functions from $[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$.

Then exists a sequence of $v_{n} \in C^\infty_{c}((a,b))$ such that for every compact $K \subset (a,b)$ $v_n$ tends uniformly to $v$"

Anyone knows a proof of this fact?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: the continuous functions are dense in $C^\infty$ take any sequence $u_n\rightarrow v$ in $C^\infty$ and then replace $u_n$ with $u_n 1_{[-n,n]}$.

Comment: @yanko You meant $C^\infty([a,b])$ is dense in $C^0([a,b])$ (convolution with $n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}$) then multiply with a $C^\infty_c$ approximation of $1_{x \in [a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]}$ (obtained from $1_{x \in [a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]} \ast \varphi_m$ where $ \varphi_m(x) = m \varphi(mx), \varphi(x) = \frac{1}{C} e^{-1/(1-x^2)}1_{|x| < 1}$)

Comment: You never said what $v$ is. You also need to say "uniformy **on $K$**"

Comment: Approximate $g\in C_0$  by continuous functions supported in $[a+1/n,b-1/n]$ and convolve these approximations with an appropriate test function.